# I got 3 Days of PhP please Forgive me but Echo is killing me... What is Wrong?

Tags: php, echo

I tried and read for hours...
I just cant get the last Echo to show a total id count.
I tried insert conditions in Select... Nope...
Please help...

As i said in the title i am new at this. 
Doing just for 'fun'
If you could help a newbie out i would appreciate that.

```
<?php
$dt = new DateTime('');
$dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Lisbon'));
echo $dt->format('d-m-Y | G:i:s');

 // START CONECTION TO BD --> 

 if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'YES_I_DID_THIS');
DEFINE ('DB_PSWD', 'THIS_TOO');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'YEAP..I CAN USE THE TABLE FINE.. ITS NOT CONNECTION');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'MYUSER');  

  $dbcon = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PSWD, DB_NAME); 
  $pnome = $_POST['pnome'];
  $unome = $_POST['unome'];
  $contacto = $_POST['contacto'];
  $morada = $_POST['morada'];
  $stamp = $_POST['stamp'];
  $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO Contactos (pnome, unome, contacto, morada, stamp) VALUES ('$pnome','$unome','$contacto','$morada','DATE: Auto CURDATE($stamp)')";


  if (!mysql_query($dbcon, $sqlinsert)) {
      die('');


      }
  $newrecord = "1 Record added to the Database";

// END INSERT DATA SCRIPT -->
}
// START COUNT TOTAL TABLE ID's
// As i said i am Noob... So i repeat this because i copied it... :) 

DEFINE ('DB_USER', '-----------');
DEFINE ('DB_PSWD', '-----------');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', '---------------');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', '-----------');  

 $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PSWD, DB_NAME); 
if (!$con) {
 die("cant connect: " . mysql_error());
 }
 mysql_select_db("$con"); 
 $sql = "SELECT id FROM Contactos";
count($t);
//help here please i can't show this '$t' to show at page. Thanks

echo $t ;
?>
```

Comment: You never declare `$t`, you just `count` it for some reason. What should it be? Also, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Comment: Please don't take this too harshly, but your question title is useless. Please state your actual problem in the title, and skip the "I'm a newbie" information.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't instantiating the `$t` variable. You kind of need to to be able to get the value and use it.
You would've seen an error about that if you turn on error reporting:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

---

Now your issue. You aren't even running the query.. You need to `mysql_query()` that `$sql`. I'd suggest you actually use sql's `COUNT()` function.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS count FROM Contactos";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
if(!$query) {
    die(mysql_error());
} else {
    $count = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

    echo $count['count']; // should have your count in there.
}
```

---

## You should stop using `mysql_*` functions. The library is deprecated.

I do understand that you've just started learning PHP and all, but it's best to start with the right libraries as `mysql_*` will be removed soon as it's an insecure library.

You should look into using `PDO` or `MySQLi` as they are more modern libraries and while you might have to overcome a hurdle to learn it, being competent in those libraries will do you the world of good!

Resources:

- [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)
- [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php)